# Custom 404 page based on dynamic Url - Server.Transfer throwing error transferring to dynamic page

Tags: asp.net, redirect, http-status-code-404, response

I capture all errors on my website and generate emails based on certain bits of inforamtion. I do this in `Global.asax` in `Application_Error`. I have implemented some code to capture `404` errors at which point it will do the following:

```
Server.ClearError();
string Redir = Settings["Custom404Page"];
Server.Transfer(Redir);
```

Redir will come out like: `PageContent/123/404_Not_Found.html` but when I pass this into `Server.Transfer` I get an error:

```
Error executing child request for PageContent/123/404_Not_Found.html
```

I don't want to use `Response.Redirect` as I need to ensure the status code of `404` is maintained which it doesn't seem to be when using `Response.Redirect`.

Does anyone have a solution to this? Am I allowed to use `Server.Transfer` like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't point `Server.Transfer` to a static page. You'll need to point it at a `.aspx` page to get it to work.

If you really want to use an HTML page, you'll need to open the HTML file, read its contents, cache it and use `Response.Write` to output it while persisting the 404 response header.

See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320439

> Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) dispatches the
>   Server.Transfer or the Server.Execute request to the appropriate
>   Internet Server Application Programming Interface (ISAPI) extension
>   based on the extension of the requesting file. For example, a request
>   for an .aspx page is dispatched to the Aspnet_isapi.dll ISAPI
>   extension.
>
> After the request is dispatched to appropriate ISAPI extension, the
>   ISAPI extension cannot call another ISAPI extension. You receive the
>   error message that is listed in the "Symptoms" section because the
>   Aspnet_isapi.dll file, which handles requests to ASP.NET pages, cannot
>   forward the request to the Asp.dll file, which handles requests to ASP
>   pages.

Comment: The content is database generated (html is just the extension I am using). Do you know if google and the like will allow the 302 to my custom page and then listen to the 404 on that page instead? I have managed to get it working like that but am concerned with the 302 before the 404.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, it's hard to say whether you'll be penalized so it's best to avoid it if you can. If the content is database generated, can you read it from the database and use `Response.Write`? Or just change the extension to `.aspx`?

Comment: I want the wrapper of the rest of the site if poss so the user can click any of the normal links. So as long as it has an extension of .aspx it will work? Will give that a go.

Comment: Well to be specific: It needs an extension that matches the extension of the originally requested file, so IIS will dispatch the request to the correct ISAPI handler.

Comment: Changing the extension to .aspx didn't help unfortunately. Looks like I might need to rethink my plan.

Comment: Is the original request for a `.aspx` page? Do you still get the same error? Have you attached the debugger and checked the value of `Redir` is correct?

Comment: I am using RouteMapping so `RouteCollection.MapPageRoute("ThreeParam", "{Action}/{ID}/{Title}.html", "~/Default.aspx");` but yes it ends up on an aspx page. `Redir` had a value of `PageContent/123/404_Not_Found.aspx` when I changed it. Is that correct?

Comment: Ok sorted it. I did `Server.Transfer` back to `Default.aspx` but set a session beforehand with a status code in. Default then handles showing the correct content and setting the Status code to 404. Thanks for your help.